# What are these basal rip up clasts in North Dakota?

Tags: earthquakes, sedimentology, stratigraphy, impacts

Ther's an graph that appears that the KT asteroid turned the rocks into rubble 3000 km away, else there was a rain of big rocks from the sky.

What are the rip up clasts and what is the way they were generated?

It's at the base of the formation, section 1, lower left.

[image]

Log from Tanis Site, North Dakota. Document from PNAS [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmbIU.gif)

1. [**Robert A. DePalma, Jan Smit, David A. Burnham, Klaudia Kuiper, Phillip L. Manning, Anton Oleinik, Peter Larson, Florentin J. Maurrasse, Johan Vellekoop, Mark A. Richards, Loren Gurche, Walter Alvarez, (2019)**: 
   "*A seismically induced onshore surge deposit at the KPg boundary, North Dakota*"
   *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences* **Apr 2019**, 201817407; DOI: 10.1073/pnas.1817407116](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2019/03/27/1817407116#xref-ref-33-1)

Comment: Please add where this came from (that will probably explain why you mention North Dakota), and explain how this *appears to show...3000 km away*

Comment: Yukatan crater to North dakota = 3000km .. Ok i'll add the reference to the OP, i couldnt find it at the time but i had saved the image to my pc as it's so fascinating. https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Yucatan,+Mexico/North+Dakota,+United+States/@31.4184379,-111.7211361,4z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x8f540ff8aad604ed:0xcccc217531083d0a!2m2!1d-89.0943377!2d20.7098786!1m5!1m1!1s0x52d7831257d8e963:0xd849a39835ecfc9!2m2!1d-101.0020119!2d47.5514926!3e0

Comment: Perhaps it's rocks from a mudflow which explains why it's in sandstone, i don't understand why it's graded and where it's from, it's clearly a result of the asteroid impact, it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: They are clasts from adjacent hillside deposited
inmediately after the [Chicxulub impact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater).**

---

The log you posted represents a sudden onshore inundation event due to the impact.

The paper you provided clarifies it [[1]](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2019/03/27/1817407116#xref-ref-33-1):

> Tanis site, which documents a turbulently deposited, rapidly emplaced
> sediment package directly overlain by the Cretaceous–Paleogene (KPg)
> boundary tonstein. The site, situated in the continental Hell Creek
> Formation in southwestern North Dakota (Fig. 1), displays
> inland-directed flow indicators and holds a mixture of Late Cretaceous
> marine and continental biota, implying that **its emplacement is related
> to sudden onshore inundation surges**.
>
> [image]
>
> **Figure 1**: Tanis Site, North Dakota.
>
> [image]
>
> **Figure 2**: Log of Tanis Site, North Dakota.

The unit 1 is described bellow. The contact between conglomerates and the point-bar is non gradational, and the rip-up clasts come from Hell Creek strata above the river (1C).

> The base of unit 1 comprises a matrix-supported, massive coarse-sand
> conglomerate, with angular pebble- **to small boulder-sized rip-up
> clasts derived from the underlying Hell Creek strata**. As shown in Fig.
> 2, the massive sand (1a) at the base of **unit 1 has a sharp
> non gradational basal contact with the underlying point-bar** surface and
> vertically grades into a thin (∼3-cm) zone of plane-parallel bedding
> of interlaminated sand–silt (lower 1b); climbing ripples (mid 1b);
> sinuous, wavy lamination (upper 1b); low-angle cross-lamination (lower
> 1c); fine, discontinuous subparallel lamination (upper 1c); and nearly
> structureless fine silt/mud near the top (1d). **Flow-direction reverses
> 180° toward the east—seaward—near the top of unit 1**

My guess is they were transported to the sand-bar from the hillside because of the sudden event, before the conglomerate clasts started to fall from the sky.

---

The whole depositional unit took place shortly, and before the iridium layer.

> Because the Tanis deposit contains ejecta throughout and is also
> capped by the KPg tonstein, **the depositional event took place
> during a narrow window of time: after impact but before deposition
> of the fine-grained KPg tonstein**. Given this constraint, we can
> deduce that the Event Deposit was emplaced within a matter of hours
> after the Chicxulub impact event.

The subsequent conglomerates are aerial deposits .The event is nicely described at the paper.

> We assume a scenario in which ejecta-curtain material, launched at
> about a 45° elevation angle and seen as the glassy or altered-glass
> spherules at Tanis, arrived before the shocked quartz that was
> launched at steep angles in a “warm fireball” produced by release of
> CO2 from shocked limestone after departure of the ejecta curtain

---

[1    **Robert A. DePalma, Jan Smit, David A. Burnham, Klaudia Kuiper, Phillip L. Manning, Anton Oleinik, Peter Larson, Florentin J. Maurrasse, Johan Vellekoop, Mark A. Richards, Loren Gurche, Walter Alvarez, (2019)**:
"*A seismically induced onshore surge deposit at the KPg boundary, North Dakota*"
*Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences* **Apr 2019**, 201817407; DOI: 10.1073/pnas.1817407116](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2019/03/27/1817407116#xref-ref-33-1)